# I can't merge similar layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, merge, overlapping-features, error-001156

I'm trying to merge several layers for a "Count Overlapping Polygon" tool which requires one layer. I have data for fire occurrence polygons in the forest from 1969 to 2016.  I can't get the layers to merge.  Using 10-3-1.  So far, I have tried to simplify a subset of layers in the attribute tables to where there is only 6 columns (FID, Shape, ObjectID, Date, Shape_Leng, Shape_Area). This still doesn't allow them to merged.

The error message is:

> error 001156 : Failed on input OID ; could not write value
>   '' to output field .

ArcGIS 10.3 Locate topic
Description

> A value could not be added to the output field. For example, text
>   values cannot be added to numeric fields, and text values cannot be
>   added to text fields if the values are longer than the field length.
>
> Solution Change the field type or increase the field length in the
>   field map properties.

It suggests to increase the field length but none of the columns have that options.

Comment: When you run Merge, remove all fields from the Field Map except for Date.

Answer (score 1):

When you run Merge, remove all fields from the Field Map except for Date.